# Calculate the area of the shown map

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

Given a `MapFragment` with any zoom level at any time, is it possible to detect the area covered by the map?

For instace, I'm at `Lat: 38.766667` and `Lon: -9.15` with the zoom level at `15.0f`, how do I calculate the area covered or how do I obtain the top left corner and bottom right coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the corners of the view area by doing:

```
googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().
//farLeft;
//farRight;
//nearLeft;
//nearRight;
//or
//latLngBounds;
```

Keep in mind that if you have tilting/inclined view the real view area is not a rectangle but a trapezoid.

Have a look at the documentation here to check what is best for you, latLngBounds gives the "smallest" rectangle, that is not the exact area!
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion